# Joining local PCs to AWS Domain

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn, amazon-web-services

My customer has AWS servers, and local computers, he not only wants to be able to access files locally from AWS but also to add those computers to the remote AWS domain.

So I know we need a VPN, but Amazon seems to allow only those in the market place.

I’ve seen OpenVPN mentioned in forums, but a little confused if this is added to an existing server OR if it needs its own server instance (of one type or another).  I’ve had a brief look at this – https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VWqRrMGHJQg – and that looks like it’s setup on its own instance (but is that just for demo purposes?)

And once I’ve got that sorted, I need to be able to add these computers to the domain.

Also, I need to ensure that general internet traffic is not going via the VPN.

- How do I set up such a VPN?
- Do we require that the server be on a separate instance?
- How should the routing be configured?

Hope this is clear enough and some kind soul can give me a few pointers.

Comment: What router/firewall the customer is using to access the Internet?

Comment: Are these AWS instances on VPC?

Comment: I believe it's a DrayTek 2860

Comment: VPC? beleive he has x3 Windows Server on AWS

Comment: I think you can setup a VPN to your AWS VPC.
Check this out https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rphaHE5FacA